# How to you write this s = ( (n % 2 ) == 0 ? "0" : "1") +s; as an if-else statement?

Tags: java

I have this method in java:

```
public static string intToBinary(int n)
{
    string s = "";
    while (n > 0)
    {
        s =  ( (n % 2 ) == 0 ? "0" : "1") +s;
        n = n / 2;
    }
    return s;
}
```

I'd like to write it without the question mark. I tried this:

```
public static String intToBinary(int n)
    {
        String s = "";
        while (n > 0){
            if ((n%2)==0) {
                s = "0";
            } else {
                s = "1";
            }
           s += s;
           n = n / 2;
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Doesn't seem to work though. Does anyone know why?

Insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: The original expression ends with `+ s`, so you should do this within your `if`/`else` blocks, not afterwards. The `+ s` has to be evaluated using the value of `s` before the assignment takes place.

Comment: Why not `return Integer.toBinaryString(n)`?

Comment: Google `what is a ternary expression java`

Comment: You need to provide a description of the program behavior and why that behavior is not the correct or desired behavior. Saying it doesn't work is not very helpful for someone reading your post.

Comment: Note that you should use do/while, unless you want `intToBinary(0)` to return `""`.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-), but the issue with your code is *appending* instead of *inserting*; I would also prefer `StringBuilder` over `+` for `String` concatenation. Like,

```
public static String intToBinary(int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (n > 0) {
        if (n % 2 != 0) {
            sb.insert(0, '1'); // s = '1' + s
        } else {
            sb.insert(0, '0'); // s = '0' + s
        }
        n >>= 1; // n /= 2, n = n / 2
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a break down of what your first solution is doing:

```
// original
s =  ( (n % 2 ) == 0 ? "0" : "1") +s; 


// 1. ternary operator into local variable
String number = ( (n % 2 ) == 0 ? "0" : "1");   
s =   number + s;


// Ternary Operator as an if else statement
String number;
if ((n % 2 ) == 0) {   
  number = "0";        
}                      
else {                 
  number = "1";        
}                      
s = number + s;
```

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ converted your first statement to this:

```
public static String intToBinary(int n) {
    String s = "";
    while (n > 0)
    {
        if ((n % 2) == 0) {
            s = "0" + s;
        } else {
            s = "1" + s;
        }
        n = n / 2;
    }

    return s;
}
```

I ran a few basic tests and it seems to give the same output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(intToBinary(10));
    System.out.println(intToBinary2(10));

    System.out.println(intToBinary(-1));
    System.out.println(intToBinary2(-1));

    System.out.println(intToBinary(1234));
    System.out.println(intToBinary2(1234));
}
```

Although that algorithm doesn't like negative numbers (in both solutions).

```
1010 
1010


10011010010 
10011010010

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are appending in the wrong place

```
public static String intToBinary(int n) {
    String s = "";
    while (n > 0){
        if ((n%2)==0) {
            // You are setting s = "0" here
            s = "0";
            // you need to prepend like this
            s = "0" + s;
        } else {
            // same thing here
            s = "1" + s;
        }
       // now here you have s = "0" + "0" or "1" + "1"
       // s += s;
       n = n / 2;
    }
    return s;
}
```